# How to add a JOIN clause to an existing WP_Query object?

Tags: wordpress, join, filter, query-builder

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

###### Background

I have a WordPress plugin that runs a WooCommerce query to filter some products, but I'd like to modify that query: it shows some wrong products and I want to JOIN it to a VIEW I've created in order to exclude some results.

My test, the basic principle is this:

```
-- base query:
SELECT * FROM wp_term_relationships AS tr 
  WHERE tr.object_id = 194584
  ;
-- results: 1

-- enhanced query:
SELECT * FROM wp_term_relationships AS tr 
  LEFT JOIN view_excludable_attributes AS v 
    ON tr.object_id = v.post_id AND tr.term_taxonomy_id = v.term_taxonomy_id
  WHERE tr.object_id = 194584
    AND v.post_id IS NULL
  ;
-- results: 0
```

This works how I want it.

###### Converting this test to functions.php

What I now don't understand is the fundamental usage of WP_Query. [The documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/) for this incredibly impenetrable and unintuitive methodology is no help. With this following code, I already have the WP_Query object and the exact time when it's being operated (or when modification is made possible):

```
function my_query( $query, $terms, $limits ) {
    // taking a look under the hood.
    var_dump($query);exit;

    return $query;
}
add_filter('plugin_query', 'my_query', 10, 3);
```

[This docs page](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/posts_join/) for `posts_join`, as well as [this SO answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/173916/143000) and [this article](https://www.ibenic.com/extending-wp-query-custom-queries-tables/), all suggest to me that I add a filter to all sitewide queries, then figure out with `if` whether it's the right one. Did I misunderstand this? But I already have the query object. Why can I not pass it as an argument to the `posts_join` filter? Or *how* do you do it? That second argument suggests that you can.

###### Things I tried: #1

```
function my_query( $query, $terms, $limits ) {
    
    add_filter('posts_join', function($join) {
        $join .= "LEFT JOIN view_excludable_attributes AS v ON wp_term_relationships.object_id = v.post_id AND wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = v.term_taxonomy_id";
        return $join;
    });
    add_filter('posts_where', function($where) {
        $where .= "v.post_id IS NULL";
        return $where;
    });

    return $query;
}
```

###### Things I tried: #2

```
function my_query( $query, $terms, $limits ) {
    
    function subscope_join( $join, &$sub_query ) {
        $join .= " LEFT JOIN view_excludable_attributes AS v ON wp_term_relationships.object_id = v.post_id AND wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = v.term_taxonomy_id ";
        return $join;
    }

    function subscope_where( $where, &$subquery ) {
        $where .= " v.post_id IS NULL ";
        return $where;
    }

    add_filter('posts_join', 'subscope_join', 10, 2);
    add_filter('posts_where', 'subscope_where', 10, 2);

    return $query;
}
```

###### Maybe something like this

```
function my_query( $query, $terms, $limits ) {

    $query = apply_filters('posts_join', " LEFT JOIN view_excludable_attributes AS v ON wp_term_relationships.object_id = v.post_id AND wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = v.term_taxonomy_id ", $query);
    // but that doesn't seem right for many reasons.
    
    $query = apply_filters('posts_join', 'subscope_join', $query->get_clauses('join'), $query);
    // but there is no get_clauses()

    // and then similarly for WHERE.

    return $query;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work using this methodology:

```
function my_query( $query, $terms, $limits ) {

    add_filter('posts_join', 'my_join', 10, 2);
    add_filter('posts_where', 'my_where', 10, 2);

    return $query;
}


function my_join( $join, $subquery ) {

    $join .= " LEFT JOIN view_excludable_attributes AS v ON wp_term_relationships.object_id = v.post_id AND wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = v.term_taxonomy_id ";
    return $join;
}


function my_where( $where, $subquery ) {

    $where .= " AND v.post_id IS NULL ";
    return $where;
}
```

The way I understand it, I don't actually touch the $query object at that time, but I use that time to set up the JOIN +WHERE filters such that they don't affect the rest of the website. And then the plugin / WordPress automatically does its thing.

And technically, it was also important to modify the query a bit – the useful [Query Monitor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/) plugin helped me find a syntax error I wouldn't have otherwise been told;  and the query actually needs a specific alias for `wp_term_relationships` .